# How to pipe custom script in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have file, where each line is pid of some process. What I would like to achieve, is displaying file descriptors summary.

So basically my steps are like this:

`ps -aux | grep -E 'riak|erlang' | tr -s " " | cut -f2 -d " " | xargs lsof -a -p $param | (wc -l per process)`

I am lost here: `$param` I don't know how to put it from stdin, also I don't have an idea how to make wc -l grouped per each `lsof -a -p` result, not for total result - I am expecting number of open files per process, not by them all.

Bonus question: How to convert such input:

```
123 foo-exe
234 bar-exe
```

(first column pid, second name)
to result like

```
123 foo-exe 1234
234 foo-exe 12344
```

where first column is pid, second is name, third is number of open files.
I know it could be different way of doing it (which I would like to know), but knowledge how to do it using bash tools would be nice :)

Comment: I don't really follow all the explanation regarding the `wc -l` per process, etc, but your long pipe can be reduced to just `ps -aux | awk '/riak/ || /erland/ {print $2}'`. You can also say `while read .. do lsof ... done < <(ps -aux | awk '/riak/ || /erland/ {print $2}')`. Also, it is a bit unclear where does the `1234` comes from in the extra column. So: try to clarify a bit more what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that riak, erlang are user names.

```
ps -e -o pid=,comm= -U riak,erlang | while read pid comm; do lsof=`lsof -a -p $param | wc -l`; echo $pid $comm $lsof; done
```

Pure lsof+awk based approach (should be faster) than earlier approach.

```
{ lsof -u riak +c 0; lsof -u erlang +c 0; } | awk '{cmd[$2]=$1;count[$2]++;}function cmp_num_idx(i1, v1, i2, v2) {return (i1 - i2);} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="cmp_num_idx"; for (pid in cmd){ printf "%10d %20s %10d\n", pid, cmd[pid], count[pid];}}'
```